# UIStackView moves it's arranged subviews to top left when all subviews are hidden within an animation block

Tags: ios, swift, uistackview

If I try to animate the hiding all the subviews of a stackview, I can see them moving towards the top left corner. On showing, they are animated coming from top left to their proper space.
If I hide only a subset of the arranged views, they are animated as expected.

My current workaround is to keep an invisible subview in the stack, but this is super wonky.

I am hiding via

```
UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5) {                
    self.someStack.arrangedSubviews.forEach { $0.isHidden = !$0.isHidden 
}
```

Comment: Hello, I have the same problem, did you find a way to solve it? thanks

Comment: Nothing completely satisfactory. I resorted to having an UIVIew wth height constrained to 0, that I never hide or remove. I set all my other views to hidden, when needed and it works well.

Comment: Thanks! I was thinking about doing the same. It's te only way

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I faced a very similar problem and after a few hours of back and forth, I found that calling `self.view.layoutIfNeeded()` fixed the issue.

My hierarchy:

`- UIView
  - UIStackView
    - UIStackView(1)
      - UIButton
      - UIButton
    - UIStackView(2)
      - UITextField
      - UIButton
      - UIActivityIndicatorView`

The root `UIView` **animates** from the bottom when the keyboard appears based on a call to `UITextField.becomeFirstResponder()` in the `(2)UIStackView`. By default, every subview of `(2)UIStackView` is hidden. Based on a `UISegmentedControl` change, the app calls `UITextField.becomeFirstResponder()` and hides `(1)UIStackView` and shows `(2)UIStackView`. If I don't call `self.view.layoutIfNeeded()` after `stackView.subviews.forEach { $0.isHidden = false }` to show the subviews of `(2)UIStackView` I see them animating from the **top left** of the device.

I don't know if this might help you, but it might be a starting point to investigate.

Answer (score 2):

Try adding an additional empty view (width/height 0) into your stack view. This fixed the issue for me.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. Works like charm for me.